# Eigenvalues after Diagonal Perturbation

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, perturbation-theory

I was looking into how perturbation changes eigenvalues of a given symmetric matrix, and I came across lot of results regarding off-diagonal perturbation. But how does diagonal perturbation affect eigenvalues.

Suppose we have the following matrices $A$ and $D$ where $A$ is our original matrix and $D$ denotes the diagonal perturbation.

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{N} & \frac{1}{N} & \ldots & \frac{1}{N}\\
\frac{1}{N} & \frac{1}{N} & \ldots & \frac{1}{N}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
\frac{1}{N} & \frac{1}{N} & \ldots & \frac{1}{N}
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$D = \begin{bmatrix}x_1 & 0 & \ldots & 0\\
0 & x_2 & \ldots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & \ldots & x_{N}
\end{bmatrix}$$

Here, all the $x_i$'s are identical and independent random variables sampled from a normal distribution $\mathcal N(0, \sigma^2)$.

Now, how do we **find the eigenvalues of the matrix $A' = A - D$**? Note that, the eigenvalues of the matrix $A$ are $1, \underbrace{0, \ldots, 0}_{N - 1 \text{ times}}$ respectively.

Comment: A specific sample of iid $N(0,\sigma)$'s will almost never have sum zero. Anyway you can use Gerschgorin but just about anything else I can think of is either distributional or numerical, especially if $\sigma$ is not very small.

Comment: Of course, but I am assuming $N$ to be large enough. Then, can I not have any better analytical bounds on the new eigenvalues?

Comment: The limit you write doesn't exist. The sum doesn't converge in any sense; its typical values become larger with increasing $N$.

Comment: The best analytical bound I can think of is that the $i$th eigenvalue is within $(N-1)/N$ of $x_i+1/N$, which is what Gerschgorin tells you.

Comment: (And even that isn't exactly true if those circles overlap, which they probably do if $N$ is large. Instead it's "each connected component $C_j$ of the union of all those circles contains a number of eigenvalues equal to the number of underlying circles in $C_j$".)

Comment: Oh okay, thanks!